# How to add a tiled menu on SharePoint 2013 landing page

Tags: 2013

SharePoint 2013 Office 365

I'd like to add a menu on the home page that uses the same type of grid tile layout as what initially comes on a new site's page...

[image]

Is there a native/already installed web part or app that allows me to add this type of tiled menu?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can add the list of tiles like this. If you want to create the tile menu like this. You should use these steps:

- Create a promotion list. Go to Site Content -> Add an app -> Choose
  Promotion Link list -> pick a name and create this list.
- Go to the list just created and add the tiles you want to show with
  title, description, link, background image...
- Go to the landing page you want to show the tile menu on: Edit page
  -> Insert this list to the page and Save.

So you will see the tile menu display on the landing page.

Comment: Great, thanks so much Mike...
Any suggestions on how to change the size of the tiles/links?